# Add new XElement to an existing XElement if it doesn't already exist

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

How do I check to see if an element exists within a given element before trying to add it?

**Background**: I have an `XDocument` `X` that contains as a child element `Flowers` which subsequently contains a series of elements that are each named `Flower`.  Each `Flower` already has 2 child elements and I would like to add a 3rd element called `Price`.  However, I want to check and make sure there's not already an element for `Price` within the `Flower` element. How do I do that? Do I even need to check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XElement` has a `HasElements` property, which would work if just wanted to know whether any elements existed or not.

For your case, I would use...

```
XNamespace ns = "http://mynamespace.com";
bool hasPrice = flowerElement.Element(ns + "Price") == null;
```

..to see if a the price element exists. If not, you can then add it.

Note: if you don't have any namespace set for your XML file, you can use `Namespace.None` instead of `ns`.

Comment: right, but each `Flower` element alredy has 2 child elements. I'm trying to see if an element called `Price` already exists as a child element. How can I do that without throwing an exception?

Comment: @Ben, I edited my answer further. This should not throw an exception.

Comment: @Ben, `ns` is the XML namespace for the `Price` element. It's normally just the default namespace. I'll add an example on how to set `ns` to my answer.

Comment: does XNamespace overload the plus operator here??